# heroku CLI auth by token

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Every time after building and pushing docker image from Gitlab registry to Heroku registry I need to execute `heroku container:release web` to Heroku run image (release), but I wanna automate this

I added heroku CLI tool installation into `gitlab-ci-yml`, but I can't auth heroku CLI by token
When I try to set HEROKU_API_KEY=token and run `heroku login` I get an error `Error: Cannot log in with HEROKU_API_KEY set`
Also tried to do this with HEROKU_DEBUG on, but debugger info couldn't help me
I can't use `~/.netrc`

**Any way to auth heroku CLI or automate releasing docker images in heroku?**

current gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
    - apt install snapd
    - snap install --classic heroku
    - HEROKU_API_KEY=$HEROKU_API_TOKEN heroku login
    - docker login -u $REGISTRY_UNAME -p $REGISTRY_PWD registry.gitlab.com
    - docker login --username=_ --password=$HEROKU_PWD registry.heroku.com
script:
    # a lot of tag & push lines
    - heroku container:release web
```

Comment: I might be missing something. Why do you have to log in if you already have the API key set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved by changing account password that causes tokens changing and re-creating new token
And then run again `HEROKU_API_KEY=token heroku container:release web` with success

Answer (score 10):

If you have set the `HEROKU_API_KEY` environment variable, you don't have to log in again. The API key will be used for the Heroku CLI commands if present.

Make sure to use `heroku authorizations:create` to create never-expiring tokens. Check [this](https://help.heroku.com/PBGP6IDE/how-should-i-generate-an-api-key-that-allows-me-to-use-the-heroku-platform-api) out for a detailed explanation.

Ref: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/502#issuecomment-309099883

Note that the `git` commands like `git push heroku master` won't use the API key. See [this](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/502#issuecomment-311141975) for more info.

Comment: no, I don't use heroku's git. I just build my image in gitlab CI and gitlab's CI delivers it to heroku. But heroku won't start running image untill I execute `heroku container:release web`. I created heroku token for auth, but gitlab's runner can't auth in heroku (to execute `heroku container:release web`) with error `Error: Cannot log in with HEROKU_API_KEY set`

Comment: @sula As I mentioned in my answer, you don't need to do `heroku login` if you already have the API key.

Comment: trying to run `HEROKU_API_KEY=never-expiring-token heroku container:release web` got an error:  Invalid credentials provided.  Error: Cannot log in with HEROKU_API_KEY set  Command failed: heroku login. Trying to run `export HEROKU_API_KEY=never-expiring-token` and then `heroku container:release web` got the same error. Also was trying the same with non-never expiring token and got the same errors